# Django form field required based on field from another form

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a form in which I would like to set the form fields 'required' based on the value from another form in the same view

Example

```
class FormA(forms.Form):
    field_a = forms.CharField()
    field_b = forms.CharField()

class FormB(forms.Form):
    field_x = forms.ChoiceField(choices = [('a', 'a'), ('b', 'b')])
```

I would like to set the fields in FormA required during the validation of the form, based on the value of fields_x in FormB. Is there a clean way to do this in django ?

Comment: is there any reason why these two forms are not combined into a single form?

Comment: In this case formA is optional depending on other conditions. They are shown or hidden dynamically using javascript. But whenever they are shown, I would like the fields to be set as required somehow.